# syntax error ruby on rails while using $ rake db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHzpD.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fM84d.png)

I have been trying to migrate my rails aplication using $ rake db:migrate I am getting this error message from the terminal. any idea of what I am doing wrong. I can see that there is a syntax error on line 42 but when I try to correct it doesn't close.

Comment: Please don't post links to pictures of code. Instead, copy, paste and format the code directly in your question. It's in your best interest to make it easy for people to help you, rather than asking them to jump through multiple hoops to help you out.

Answer (score 1):

I see a period after `class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration` in line 1 of the migration, like so:

```
class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration.
```

That period shouldn't be there

Answer (score 1):

There is a period present in 1st line. which gives syntax error.